# I want to check if the SSL certificate for a certain link is valid

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

python

```
import requests
import ssl
from datetime import datetime

def check_ssl_certificate(url):
    try:
        # SSL証明書の取得
        response = requests.get(url, verify=True)
        cert = ssl.get_server_certificate((url, 443))
        
        # 証明書情報を解析
        x509 = ssl.PEM_cert_to_DER_cert(cert)
        x509 = ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(x509)
        
        # 有効期限を取得
        x509_info = ssl._ssl._test_decode_cert(x509)
        valid_from = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x509_info['notBefore'])
        valid_to = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x509_info['notAfter'])
        
        # 現在の日時を取得
        current_time = datetime.utcnow()
        
        # 有効期限の比較
        if current_time >= valid_from and current_time <= valid_to:
            print("valid")
        else:
            print("invalid")
        
    except requests.exceptions.SSLError as e:
        print("can't receive the sslcertificate")

# チェックするURLを指定
url = 'https://www.google.com'

# SSL証明書の有効性を確認
check_ssl_certificate(url)
```

error statement

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\uc100\Programing\Python\Codingspace\everything\check.py", line 36, in <module>
    check_ssl_certificate(url)
  File "c:\Users\uc100\Programing\Python\Codingspace\everything\check.py", line 9, in check_ssl_certificate
    cert = ssl.get_server_certificate((url, 443))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\uc100\Programing\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1527, in get_server_certificate
    with create_connection(addr, timeout=timeout) as sock:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\uc100\Programing\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 827, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\uc100\Programing\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 962, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

I want to check if the SSL certificate for a certain link is valid by python.However, an error statement like the one shown above is output.I have no idea what the error message is saying, so please tell me if you know what it means.please.

Comment: `get_server_certificate` expects a hostname (i.e. `www.google.com`) and not a URL (`https://www.google.com`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the expired date you can do:

```
import datetime
import socket
import ssl
def get_date_before_expired(hostname, port = '443'):
    """
    Get expired date of ssl cert
    """    
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with socket.create_connection((hostname, port)) as sock:
        with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
            cert_info = ssock.getpeercert()
            expiry_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(cert_info['notAfter'], '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z')
            print(expiry_date)
            return expiry_date
if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_date_before_expired('www.google.com')
```